# Form handling in net beans desktop applications

Tags: java, netbeans

hello I have a basic Java ability when it comes to writing code and creating such things as calcs and booking system, I am wanting to use the Desktop application in netbeans for a more professional look but I carnt manage to switch between visual forms i have created using buttons, in vb I would just set the form as me.visible(False) and Form2.visible(true). Any ideas guys thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well it is very similar in Java too instead of typing

```
MyForm().visible(true)
```

Use

```
MyForm().setVisible(true);
```

Basically if you clicked a button and you wanted a new form to be displayed it would look something like

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
    new TestForm().setVisible(true);
}
```